# How to access CDI managed bean from JAX-RS MessageBodyWriter?

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi, apache-tomee

I'm struggling with accessing CDI managed beans from a JAX-RS message body handler in TomEE.

My handler class (`implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>, MessageBodyReader<Object>`) is registered via the `cxf.jaxrs.providers` property in `openejb-jar.xml`. When I use the `@Inject` annotation on the constructor, the handler is silently ignored (because it then lacks a no-arg constructor). When using field injection instead, the field stays empty. Obviously, message body handlers are entirely unmanaged in TomEE (CXF).

I tried getting the BeanManager via JNDI, but that fails without logging an exception.

Is there any other way to do this, or am I doing something wrong? Alternatively, I would of course appreciate a way to make the handler itself managed, and register it programmatically somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Injection should work just fine in versions of CXF >= 2.7. Prior versions utilize JAX-RS 1.x, which is *not* tightly integrated with CDI. In particular, JAX-RS 1.x providers, even in the presence of a CDI container, are managed by the JAX-RS runtime (not the CDI one), and **only** support the following injection annotations:

- @Resource
- @Resources
- @EJB
- @EJBs
- @WebServiceRef
- @WebServiceRefs
- @PersistenceContext
- @PersistenceContexts
- @PersistenceUnit
- @PersistenceUnits

References:

- [JAX-RS 1.0 specification, Section 6.2](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxrs-1.0-final-spec.pdf)
- [JAX-RS 2.0 specification, Section 10.2.3](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-pfd-spec/339-spec.pdf)
- [Apache CXF - Migrating from JAX-RS 1.1 to 2.0](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-MigratingfromJAXRS1.1to2.0)